# <DATA> prevents foreach loop from being executed, why? :)

Tags: perl, foreach

I have two nested foreach loops. If I use this code:

```
foreach (@directories) {
    my $actual_directory = $_;
    print "\nactual directory: ".$actual_directory."\n";

    foreach (@files) {
        my $file_name = $_; 
        my $actual_file = $actual_directory.$file_name;
        print $actual_file."\n";

        open(DATA, $actual_file) or die "Nelze otevřít zdrojový soubor: $!\n";
        my $line_number = 0;

        #   while (<DATA>){
        #       my @znaky = split(' ',$_);
        #       my $poradi = $znaky[0]; #poradi nukleotidu
        #       my $hodnota = $znaky[1]; #hodnota

        #       my @temp = $files_to_sum_of_lines{$actual_file};
        #       $temp[$line_number] += $hodnota;    
        #       $files_to_sum_of_lines{$actual_file} = @temp;

        #       $line_number+=1;
        #   }
        #   close(DATA); 
    }
}
```

I got this output:

```
actual directory: /home/n/Plocha/counting_files/1/

/home/n/Plocha/counting_files/1/a.txt
/home/n/Plocha/counting_files/1/b.txt

actual directory: /home/n/Plocha/counting_files/2/

/home/n/Plocha/counting_files/2/a.txt
/home/n/Plocha/counting_files/2/b.txt
```

However, if I uncomment "`while (<DATA>){ }`", I loose a.txt and b.txt, so the output looks like this:

```
actual directory: /home/n/Plocha/counting_files/1/

/home/n/Plocha/counting_files/1/a.txt
/home/n/Plocha/counting_files/1/b.txt

actual directory: /home/n/Plocha/counting_files/2/

/home/n/Plocha/counting_files/2/
/home/n/Plocha/counting_files/2/
```

How can this `while (<DATA>)` prevent my foreach from being executed? 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to not using `DATA`, try using lexical loop variables, and lexical filehandles. Also, Perl's built-in `$.` keeps track of line numbers for you.

```
for my $actual_directory (@directories) {
    print "\nactual directory: ".$actual_directory."\n";

    foreach my $file_name (@files) {
        my $actual_file = $actual_directory.$file_name;
        print $actual_file."\n";

        open my $INPUT, '<', $actual_file
            or die "Nelze otevřít zdrojový soubor: $!\n";

        while (my $line = <$INPUT>) {
               my @znaky = split(' ', $line);
               my $poradi = $znaky[0]; #poradi nukleotidu
               my $hodnota = $znaky[1]; #hodnota
               @temp = $files_to_sum_of_lines{$actual_file};
               $temp[ $. ] += $hodnota;
               $files_to_sum_of_lines{$actual_file} = @temp;
        }
        close $INPUT; 
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I can't quite tell if there is a logic error in there. Something like the following might be useful:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;

use Carp;
use File::Find;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile canonpath );

my %counts;
find(\&count_lines_in_files, @ARGV);

for my $dir (sort keys %counts) {
    print "$dir\n";
    my $dircounts = $counts{ $dir };
    for my $file (sort keys %{ $dircounts }) {
        printf "\t%s: %d\n", $file, $dircounts->{ $file };
    }
}

sub count_lines_in_files {
    my $file = canonpath $_;
    my $dir  = canonpath $File::Find::dir;
    my $path = canonpath $File::Find::name;

    return unless -f $path;

    $counts{ $dir }{ $file } = count_lines_in_file($path);
}

sub count_lines_in_file {
    my ($path) = @_;

    my $ret = open my $fh, '<', $path;

    unless ($ret) {
        carp "Cannot open '$path': $!";
        return;
    }
    1 while <$fh>;

    my $n_lines = $.;

    close $fh
        or croak "Cannot close '$path': $!";

    return $n_lines;
}
```

Comment: It seems that when $_ is overwritten in the while loop, it is also changing the files array. Since it goes until $_ is undef, in the next iteration of the directory loop, @files contains only undefs :D

Comment: @Sinan, typo - I think you mean `while <$DATA>` to reference your lexical fh rather than the built-in DATA handle.  Perhaps it's best to avoid any `*whatever{DATA}` when naming a filehandle :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that works and it is indeed much clearer solution:)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice! Lexical filehandles are the milk of the Gods and yet the OP chose a global file handle named `DATA` aargh! One small point, using a variable name in all caps often denotes something special, like globalness or built-in-ity, but when it comes down to it, thats just style/readability.

Comment: @JoelBerger Thanks for the compliment. I normally use all lowercase filehandles, but in this case, I just quickly changed `DATA` to `$DATA` to `$INPUT`. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Perl uses [`__DATA__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) to make a pseudo-data file at the end of the package. You can access that using the filehandle `DATA`, e.g. [`<DATA>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html). Is it possible that your filehandle is conflicting? Try changing the filehandle to something else and see if it works better.