# Beginner Perl Print

Tags: perl, text, printing, input

So I have this assignment for a beginner course in Perl and I have done some stuff and they worked out good, but i've totally run into a brick wall here and I can't get any further, and my guess is the answer is really simple only that I can't seem to fix it.

I have a text file with some text in it, simply what I'm trying to do is write the content of that file to the Terminal, this I can do with

```
open (DATA, "example.txt") or die "an error occured: $!";

while(<DATA>)
{
print "$_\n";
}
```

But, I also need to add numbering to each line of the output and I'm trying with $. but that only gives me a "1" as an output, I have been trying different stuff here all morning but I can't seem to figure this out.

What I want is an output that looks like this:

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
2. consectetur adipiscing elit
3. Maecenas iaculis vulputate eros
4. ----
5. ----

And so on.

Anyone that can help me out with this?

Comment: $. works for me with your sample code and `print "$. $_\n"` - can you post what you tried?

Comment: Yeah that worked, I thought you could only have one $ inside the "" so i tried doing it like "$." "$_\n"; Which didnt work out.

Comment: You may find that adding `\n` to your print gives you one newline too many, since the line you read from the file already contains a newline.

Comment: For your "didn't work out" attempt, you would have needed to put either a `,` (print the first string, followed by the second) or a `.` (concatenate the two strings into one string and print that) between `"$."` and `"$_\n"`. Also, there's no need for double quotes if a variable is the only thing between them, so you could also do it as `print $., $_, "\n";`, although martin's version is what I would normally use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open (DATA, "example.txt") or die "an error occured: $!";

while(<DATA>) {
  print "$.. $_\n";
}
```

To start a new line after every sentence (full stop followed by at least one blank), you could use something like the following:

```
$line = 0;
while(<DATA>)
{
  @lines = split /\. +/;
  for (@lines) {
    ++$line;
    print "$line. $_\n";
  }
}
```

(Very likely there is a better perl idiom for this …)

Comment: Is there a way Perl can recognize a . at the end of a sentance and start a new line and number that line aswell? or do the structure of the textfile have to be "sentance."[newline]

Comment: @user998836: You didn't mention that requirement in your original question …

Comment: `perl -nwe 'print "$. $_"' file.txt`

Comment: @TLP: yes, but this will not work when he wants to count sentences instead of lines. Will assigning `$/` with my regex work in that case?

Comment: @knittl `$/` is a string, not a regex. I tried setting it to `"."` and `". "`, but output was somewhat unshapely and unpredictable, so I discarded the idea. It works with line numbers, though.

Answer (score 2):

Please, PLEASE do not open a file with the filehandle `DATA`!! First of all, this just happened here yesterday, and it causes all kinds of [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7767541/468327)! Second, `DATA` is a special handle for using content which is kept at the bottom of a script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
  print "Hello $_\n";
}

__DATA__
Joel
Larry
```

Third and most importantly, you should be using more modern Perl, using the 3-arg open and lexical file handles!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
#if you don't want to do "or die" all the time
#use autodie;

open( my $handle, '<', "example.txt" ) or die "$!";
while(<$handle>) {
  #do whatever
}
```

If your teacher/textbook doesn't use anything from the Modern Perl movement, you should inform them, or get a [new book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html).

Comment: ++mod! I was going to mention the part of using `DATA` as a filehandle name, but you've beat me to it. Plus, you've mentioned a lot of other good information. And, the link to the book. (I'll have to look at it). I like the Llama book, but it really is a bit dated in many ways and doesn't go through a lot of newer stuff. The big problem is that many people pick up the Llama book, learn Perl, then never pick up another Perl book.